# how to extend RAM for Python out of memory problem?

Tags: python, ram

I am running big dataset for machine learning and my laptop memory is limited (8GB)

and Python is giving me this error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.34 GiB for an array with shape (49998, 3607) and data type float64
```

when i run this line

```
df_features = df_features.pivot(index='RepID', columns='Code', values='Frequency')
```

How can I use USB stick as a RAM or how to use HDD as RAM with python?

Comment: If you have a [swap partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Unix_and_Unix-like_systems) mounted your OS should use that for swapping. Keep in mind that swapping to HDD is very, very slow, and likely even slower to a thumbdrive. If you want to use hard disk as memory, you should use a much faster SSD. Though it is preferable to just extend your RAM, if possible.

Comment: Another approach is to reduce the size of the arrays or the resolution of the data you are dealing with.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I checked Virtual Memory size in my computer, it says "Automatically Managed" that means it is already active? then why Python does not use it?

Comment: I do not know what that means. Each OS will have a different way to set up a swap drive, I think dealing with that here is out of the scope of SO.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Thanks, looks like it is working with swap partition :)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa plz make your comment an answer to mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a swap partition mounted your OS should use that for swapping. Keep in mind that swapping to HDD is very, very slow, and likely even slower to a thumbdrive. If you want to use hard disk as memory, you should use a much faster SSD. Though it is preferable to just extend your RAM, if possible.

Another approach is to reduce the size of the arrays or the resolution of the data you are dealing with.